# A generic question about heterogeneous container?

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning the effective java, I found a question for heterogeneous container. When I set a value into heterogeneous container, IDEA IDE give me a error:

```
'putFavorite(java.lang.Class<capture<? extends java.lang.String>>, capture<? extends java.lang.String>)' in 'com.kai.java.Favorites' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Class<capture<? extends java.lang.String>>, java.lang.String)'
```

my code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
        favorites.putFavorite(String.class, "12345");
        favorites.putFavorite(String.class, "5678");
        favorites.putFavorite("123".getClass(), "999999"); // error
    }
}


class Favorites {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        favorites.put(Objects.requireNonNull(type), instance);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(favorites.get(type));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question correct, else the experts for that topic will not find your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the signatur of `putFavorite` to

```java
public <T> void putFavorite(Class<? extends T> type, T instance)
```

Note the use of `? extends T` instead of just `T`.

Comment: Note: `getFavorite` should probably be changed too for the same reason

Comment: @Lino This is not necessary for the code to compile.

Comment: I know, because the actual result type(the return value of getClass) is {@code Class<? extends |X|>} where {@code |X|} is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which {@code getClass} is called. Thank you